# Constant "System program problem detected" error on fresh install

Tags: release-freya

Very frustrating, completely fresh installation, within minutes I get this error. happens on every reboot

Comment: Add a screenshot

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more information on this. Does anything appear to crash when this happens?